# How to store the uploaded file to s3 bucket in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, xmpp

I'm working on one to one chat with ejabberd.

I need to store the media files shared between the users to be stored in the s3 bucket.

Do I need to add the s3 bucket URL to the `docroot` of `mod_http_upload` module?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: @VipinCP No. I didn't find any solution for this.